# How to fix a Paypal CRYPTOSERV_SERVER_ERROR

Tags: paypal

I've been using Paypal's payment standard with dynamically encrypted buttons for successfully for several years. It suddenly stopped working on 19/05/2022.

When a customer clicks on the payment button they're taken to Paypal and are shown the error page with the 'helpful' message "Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later.". The headers served by Paypal along with this page include `code=CRYPTOSERV_SERVER_ERROR`, which I've googled and there are no results. All certificates are still valid.

Does anyone have a clue what this error means?

Comment: I'm unable to answer my question as to Paypal's CRYPTO_SERVER_ERROR, but I did solve my problem. Turns out that I'd been padding the encrypted field of the button with some white space, and for years paypal must have been stripping this before trying to decrypt, but as of last week (19/05/2022) they stopped stripping this whitespace and decryption failed. Removing the white space from my button solved this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I had the same problem, paypal confirmed that it is a known issue on their end without any further information or timeframe for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The May 19th mysterious PayPal error solved by a combination of trimming white space and removing line breaks worked for me. No thanks to PayPal CS who never got back to me after a week of shop being down!

```
$encryptedButton = str_replace("\n", "", $encryptedButton);
$encryptedButton = trim($encryptedButton);
```

Answer (score 1):

`<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="$encryptedText" />`

Make sure to add: `$encryptedText = str_replace("\n", "", $encryptedText);` so that extra spaces are removed.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. Still no resolution from PayPal after I reported that 5 days ago.

What I found in my page source is that the encrypted field's value was "split" with new lines, for better readability, like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7-----
MIIIoQYJKoZIhvcNAQcDoIIIkjCCCI4CAQAxggEwMIIBLAIBADCBlDCBjjELMAkG
A1UEBhMCVVMxCzAJBgNVBAgTAkNBMRYwFAYDVQQHEw1Nb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3MRQw
EgYDVQQKEwtQYXlQYWwgSW5jLjETMBEGA1UECxQKbGl2ZV9jZXJ0czERMA8GA1UE
...
```

I removed the new lines with this simple step:

```
$encryptedButton = str_replace("\n", "", $encryptedButton);
```

And now the button seems to work again.